# Difference between "current" and "present"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference, word-in-context

Both of words have the same meaning so when I would use "current" and present"?

Comment: Your question would be better received here if you put more work into it, and followed the guidance in our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post. It's only been active for half an hour, and it already has two close votes.

Answer (score 4):

There are situations where current and present can be exchanged with each other. In other cases this would result in a different meaning or would just sound odd.

1. As adjectives they are interchangeable if you mean "now". Like:

   - the current/present situation
2. You cannot substitute one with the other in the following examples:

   The adjective/adverb "present" can mean:

   - attendant, not absent (e.g.: I am present = I am here)

   You would not say "I am current".

   "current" can mean:

   - popular, established (e.g.: The current fashion)
   - ongoing (e.g.: current transactions)
     in these cases you would not use present.

These are just two examples and of course don't cover all the cases where the meaning of current and present differs.

3. If you use it as a noun, the meanings differ:

   **The current** can mean drift or electricity among other meanings. 
   **The present** can mean gift or present time.
   (see dictionary)

Comment: I think the O.P. already understands what you have listed as #1. I think this question is more about your #2 – when would you use one instead of the other?

Comment: I know, I just added #1 since it wasn't specified if noun or adjective was meant and I do not know the other persons level of knowledge. Since it wasn't a lot of extra text I thought a thorough answer is better. Especially, if you consider that other people with a similar question, but maybe less language knowledge search for an explanation.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not saying you should remove #1, but I do think you maybe ought to try to beef up #2.